# How to get updated cart subtotal in checkout_cart_product_add_after event observer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, totals

I want to add a free product to cart with another product. For that I wrote `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event observer. My problem is, I don't get the updated cart subtotal(after adding first product, it returns subtotal as 0). This is my observer code.

```
namespace StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class AddfreeProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $formKey;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey){
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $totals = $this->cart->getQuote()->getTotals();
        $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']->getValue();  
        $this->logger->debug($subtotal);
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Discusstion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44527/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-keerthana

Comment: see this related thread, it may useful https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182356/cart-items-not-updating-properly-in-magento-2/183506#183506

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cart items not updating properly in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182356/cart-items-not-updating-properly-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

We should use `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
 */
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    .....
)
{
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

}
```

Try to get the totals:

```
//Get totals
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getTotals();
//Get sub total.
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: Thanks Khoa, for your answer. But, my bad luck, it is not working :(

Comment: You tried to dump out the data? Actually, your question also make me confused. You want to know the collect total data or you want to add an extra fee?

Comment: I just want to get cart subtotal. But in checkout_cart_product_add_after observer I don't get it by using the code I mentioned above.

Comment: You tried to dump out this data?

Comment: Yes, I have used logger to print this data. But it displays 0.

Comment: `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->collectTotals();` => always show 0?

Comment: When using this, my product cant be added, and I tried it in a controller but it shows nothing.

Comment: My actual problem is $this->cart->getQuote()->getTotals(); is working fine in other controller and block. But it is not showing updated value in this observer.

Comment: Seem your issue is more difficult, please update your question more details.

Comment: I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: try to use: `$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getTotals();`

Comment: It is not working, same issue again, when I use this code, my product cant be added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44527/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-keerthana).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$this->_cartTotalRepository using \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CartTotalRepository

$totals = $this->_cartTotalRepository->get($this->cart->getQuote()->getId());
// Subtotal
$subtotal = (float) $totals->getSubtotal();
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the updated cart subtotal in the checkout_cart_product_add_after event observer in Magento 2, you can use the following code:

```
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class YourObserver implements ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $cart;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
        ) {
            $this->cart = $cart;
        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $cartSubtotal = $this->cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
            // Do something with the cart subtotal
        }
    }
```

Here, we are injecting the Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart class in the constructor of the observer. This class provides methods to work with the current cart.

In the execute() method of the observer, we are getting the current cart subtotal by calling the getSubtotal() method on the quote object. The quote object represents the current cart and provides methods to work with the cart data.

Once you have the cart subtotal, you can perform any necessary actions on it within the observer.