# Cart items not updating properly in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

As per functionality product have different `Tier Prices` and customers have different `Customer Groups`. When customer adding product to cart we need to add product of the first `Tier Price`.

Example:

Product Name: Test Product, SKU: TP.

**Tier Prices:**

Customer Group: Not Logged, Qty: 1, Price: $2

Customer Group: Retailer, Qty: 10, Price: $18

Customer Group: Retailer, Qty: 30, Price: $15

Customer Group: Wholesale, Qty: 100, Price: $150

Customer Group: Wholesale, Qty: 200, Price: $100

1) If the **Not Logged customer** adding this product to cart it will add based on customer requested `Qty` like 1,2,3 etc..

2) If the **Retailer Customer** is requested 16 `Qty`, it will add `Qty` by fallowing logic.

1. Remainder = Requested Qty/First Tier Price;
2. MultipleQty = round(Remainder);
3. FinalQty = First Tier Price * MultipleQty

if customer requested 16 `Qty`.

1. Remainder = 16/10; i.e remainder will be = 1.6
2. MultipleQty = round(1.6); i.e MultipleQty will be = 2;
3. FinalQty = 2*10; i.e FinalQty = 20;

So here 20 `Qty` will be added to cart.

Here is the Question. If **Retail Customer** forgot to login and requested 16 `Qty` before login it will add as per Not logged customer logic i.e 16 `Qty`. After Some time **Retail Customer** Login any where, we need to convert the Shopping cart products as per above ( 2 Point) logic right?. For this I have created Event `customer_login` to convert **Shopping Cart** product `Qty`'s as per above logic.

My code is working, When Shopping Cart have only one product.

But my code something went wrong, When Shopping cart have multiple `Tier Price` products.

For this stuff I have written below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="custom_customer_log_login" instance="ABCSolutions\LimitCartQty\Observer\UpdateCartQtyBasedOnCustomerGroupAtObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer Code**

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\LimitCartQty\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface ;

class UpdateCartQtyBasedOnCustomerGroupAtObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $_customerCartSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $_cartHelper;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ){
        $this->_customerCartSession = $cart;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request_qty = 0;
        $tierPriceQty = [];
        $productIDs = [];
        $bcw = 0;

        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $productIDs[] = (int) $item->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $tierPrice = $product->getTierPrices();
            $isFirst = false;
            if(count($tierPrice) > 0){
                foreach($tierPrice as $k => $v){
                    if($v->getCustomerGroupID()== $this->_customerCartSession->getCustomerSession()->getCustomerGroupId()){
                        if(!$isFirst){
                            $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = $v->getQty();
                            $isFirst = true;
                            $bcw++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!isset($tierPriceQty[$bcw]) && !($isFirst)){
                    $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = "No Tier Price";
                    $bcw++;
                }

            }else{
                $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = "No";
                $bcw++;
            }
        }

        $i=0;

        foreach($productIDs as $productId){

            unset($params);
            try{

                $productAdded = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
                $productSku = $productAdded->getSku();
                $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
                $item= $quote->getItemByProduct($productAdded);
                $itemId= $item->getItemId();
                $cartQty = $item->getQty();
                $isNumber = is_numeric($tierPriceQty[$i]);
                $remainder = 0;

                if($isNumber){
                    $oldQty = $tierPriceQty[$i];

                    $remainder = $cartQty / $oldQty;
                    $multiplyQty = round($remainder);
                    $finalQty = $oldQty * $multiplyQty;
                }else{
                    if($tierPriceQty[$i] == "No"){
                        $finalQty = $cartQty;
                        $oldQty = $finalQty;
                    }elseif($tierPriceQty[$i] == "No Tier Price"){
                        $finalQty = $cartQty;
                        $oldQty = $finalQty;
                    }

                }

                if($finalQty == 0 || $oldQty < $finalQty){
                    $params[$itemId]['qty'] = number_format($oldQty, 0, '.', '');
                }else{
                    $params[$itemId]['qty'] = number_format($finalQty, 0, '.', '');
                }

                $this->_customerCartSession->updateItems($params);
                $this->_customerCartSession->saveQuote();
                $this->_customerCartSession->save();
                $i++;

            }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->_messageManager->addError(
                    $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
                $i++;
                continue;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t update the shopping cart.'));
                $objectManager->create('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Have you looked into the Persistent Cart for further details on how such is implemented in the core? https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Persistent

Comment: @B00MER Not yet. Don't know functionality of `Magento_Persistent`. If possible give me a solution?

Comment: @SohelRana any help?

Comment: @Marius any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I did it.

```
<?php

namespace ABCSolutions\LimitCartQty\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface ;

class UpdateCartQtyBasedOnCustomerGroupAtObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $_customerCartSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $_cartHelper;

    /**
     * @var ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_messageManager;


    protected $_responseFactory;

    protected $quoteRepository;


    protected $_url;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ){
        $this->_customerCartSession = $cart;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

        //$event = $observer->getEvent();
        //$RedirectUrl= $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost');
        //$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($RedirectUrl)->sendResponse();

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        //$cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request_qty = 0;
        $tierPriceQty = [];
        $productIDs = [];
        $bcw = 0;

        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $productIDs[] = (int) $item->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $tierPrice = $product->getTierPrices();
            $isFirst = false;
            if(count($tierPrice) > 0){
                foreach($tierPrice as $k => $v){
                    if($v->getCustomerGroupID()==  $this->_customerCartSession->getCustomerSession()->getCustomerGroupId()){
                        if(!$isFirst){
                            $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = $v->getQty();
                            $isFirst = true;
                            $bcw++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!isset($tierPriceQty[$bcw]) && !($isFirst)){
                    $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = "No Tier Price";
                    $bcw++;
                }

            }else{
                $tierPriceQty[$bcw] = "No";
                $bcw++;
            }
        }

        $this->UpdateShoppingCart($productIDs,$tierPriceQty);

        return true;

    }


    public function UpdateShoppingCart($productIDs = array(), $tierPriceQty = array()){

        $i=0;
        $params = array();
        foreach($productIDs as $productId){

            //unset($params);
            $isTierPrice = false;
            try{

                $productAdded = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
                $productSku = $productAdded->getSku();
                $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
                $item= $quote->getItemByProduct($productAdded);
                $itemId= $item->getItemId();
                $cartQty = $item->getQty();
                $isNumber = is_numeric($tierPriceQty[$i]);
                $remainder = 0;

                if($isNumber){
                    $oldQty = $tierPriceQty[$i];

                    $remainder = $cartQty / $oldQty;
                    $multiplyQty = round($remainder);
                    $finalQty = $oldQty * $multiplyQty;
                }else{
                    if($tierPriceQty[$i] == "No"){
                        //$finalQty = $cartQty;
                        //$oldQty = $finalQty;
                        $isTierPrice = true;
                    }elseif($tierPriceQty[$i] == "No Tier Price"){
                        //$finalQty = $cartQty;
                        //$oldQty = $finalQty;
                        $isTierPrice = true;
                    }

                }
                if(!$isTierPrice){
                    if($finalQty <= 0){
                        $params[$itemId]['qty'] = number_format($oldQty, 0, '.', '');
                    }else{
                        $params[$itemId]['qty'] = number_format($finalQty, 0, '.', '');
                    }


                }else{
                    //$isTierPrice = false;
                    $params[$itemId]['qty'] = number_format($cartQty, 0, '.', '');
                }

                $i++;

            }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->_messageManager->addError(
                    $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage())
                );
                $i++;
                continue;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->_messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t update the shopping cart.'));
                $objectManager->create('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        }

            if(is_array($params)){
                $cartData = $this->_customerCartSession->suggestItemsQty($params);
                $this->_customerCartSession->updateItems($cartData)->save();
                //$this->_customerCartSession->saveQuote();
                //$this->_customerCartSession->save();

                $quote =  $this->_customerCartSession->getQuote();
                $customerId = $this->_customerCartSession->getCustomerSession()->getCustomerId();
                if($customerId == null){
                    $customerId = 0;
                }
                if($quote->getId() != null ){
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quote->getId());
                    $quote->setCustomerId($customerId); // Whatever you want to update
                    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
                }
            }


    }

}
```